# Illustrator (newbie) CC 2017. delete drawing behind my object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, creative-cloud, embed

I drew this vector path (i think its a vector) with the brush tool in illustrator based on the hand drawing/scan you see in the pic.  Now, I can't get rid of the hand drawing.  it moves with the path/object. 
Greatly appreciate it if you can tell me how to unlink it.  Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your items are grouped together, go ahead an *Ungroup* them.

*Right Click* > *Ungroup* (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**G**</kbd>)

You can also use the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>**A**</kbd>) to select the paths (even if they're grouped).

Comment: yes that worked.  thank you my sushi image is coming along now